# Downloading Bike-Lane Network (nodes and edges) as a KML or Shapefile

Tags: osmnx

I'm interested in using OSMnx to view the entire bike lane network of a city (say, San Francisco), and then downloading that network (nodes and edges) as a KML or shapefile. I've been able to plot the network just fine, but am struggling with extracting it as a map layer I can use in ESRI, Google Earth, etc.

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd

useful_tags = ox.settings.useful_tags_way + ['cycleway'] + ['bicycle']
ox.utils.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True, useful_tags_way=useful_tags)
G = ox.graph_from_place(query = 'San Francisco, California, USA', network_type='bike', simplify=False,  retain_all=True)

non_cyc = []
for u,v,k,d in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    bi = False
    if "bicycle" in d: #kind of uggly but not every edge has the bicycle tag
        if d['bicycle']=='designated':
            bi = True

    if d['highway']=='cycleway':
        pass
    elif 'cycleway' in d:
        pass
    elif bi:
        pass
    else:
        non_cyc.append((u,v,k))

G.remove_edges_from(non_cyc)
G = ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(G)
G = ox.simplify_graph(G)
stats = ox.stats.basic_stats(G)
print(stats["edge_length_total"])
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

[sf_bike_network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23E3v.png)

Within a Google Colab notebook, I've been stymied in terms of downloading this network as a KML, GeoJSON, or Shapefile. The files I have been able to export either only have 1 or two edges, tops.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to download files from Google Colab? Are you asking how to save graphs to disk with OSMnx?

Answer (score 0):

> I've been able to plot the network just fine, but am struggling with extracting it as a map layer I can use in ESRI

The OSMnx [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#osmnx.io.save_graph_geopackage) explains how to save your graph to disk, including as a GeoPackage to use in any other GIS tool (like ESRI's). Probably best to avoid using Shapefiles whenever possible at this point: http://switchfromshapefile.org/

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True

# download the network
useful_tags = ox.settings.useful_tags_way + ["cycleway"] + ["bicycle"]
G = ox.graph_from_place("San Francisco, California, USA", network_type="bike",  retain_all=True)

# save a GeoPackage to use in ESRI ArcGIS
ox.save_graph_geopackage(G, "sf_bike.gpkg")
```